# How to ensure IPv6 link-local address format with MAC

Tags: linux, ipv6, link-local-address

On my custom Yocto Linux build, I want to use IPv6 link local address. I have got address `fe80::bdc2:521:a893:b757/64`, but my MAC address is `e4:5f:01:75:d3:04`. As I know, they should correspond. I'm not sure, how persistent will this address be. How can I force it to use MAC based address? On all my other linux computers, this works as that, except Raspberry Pi with Raspbian installed.

Comment: What makes you think that they should correspond ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I know, they should correspond

That's not a requirement. Link-local addresses still use Neighbor Discovery, so there is nothing that requires a specific format for them.

> I'm not sure, how persistent will this address be.

Depends on what software generated it. Non-MAC-based addresses are *likely* to use RFC7217-style hash-based generation; userspace software such as systemd-networkd would automatically use a file-based seed such as `/etc/machine-id` – but on the other hand, the in-kernel address assignment code does not have a way to generate and store the seed, so the address would only be persistent if the `.stable_secret` sysctl is manually set.

> How can I force it to use MAC based address?

If the address was assigned by the kernel (i.e. shows `proto kernel_ll`), set the interface's `addrgenmode` parameter to `eui64`:

- Via netlink: `ip link set eth0 addrgenmode eui64`
- Via sysctl: `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.addr_gen_mode=0`

Comment: I'm using network-manager, but "nmcli addr_gen_mode" keyword search did the trick. Thanks.